# Vaadin: Vertical Table

Tags: java, database, layout, vaadin

I'm trying to figure out how to use Vaadin to make a vertical table, i.e.:

```
Caption element 1: | Table Row 1 info | Table Row 2 info | Table Row 3 info
Caption element 2: | Table Row 1 info | Table Row 2 info | Table Row 3 info
Caption element 3: | Table Row 1 info | Table Row 2 info | Table Row 3 info
Caption element 4: | Table Row 1 info | Table Row 2 info | Table Row 3 info
```

This type of layout is completely absent from the book of vaadin (though a very short example of icon based row headers is given) and also absent from discussion in forums.

Does anyone familiar with Vaadin know how this layout can be achieved?

Comment: Why do you need Table to this case, isn't VerticalLayout sufficient?

Comment: For 3 reasons, for integration with my export to CSV functionality, to match the l&f of the rest of the app, and because tables are a very efficient way to show compunded info from a data source.

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps hide the table header by:

```
Table t = new Table();
t.setColumnHeaderMode(Table.COLUMN_HEADER_MODE_HIDDEN);
```

And after that you use a cellStyleGenerator combined with a TableFieldFactory to achive your specific layout. However, I agree with you that this option is missing from the standard vaadin table.